# trouble with php flatfile

Tags: php, flat-file

So im trying to write to a flatfile. A word from a database is written every time it meets a certain criteria. The problem is after the script runs, only the last word that met the criteria shows up in the file. Obviously the words are being written, then over written by the next word. How can i fix this? I want each word to be written to its own line. Heres my code.

```
<?php

include 'special.class.php';
require 'db_config.php';


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM words limit 0, 30") or die ("Could not make query");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$word = $row['result'];



$special_word = new word_stuffs( $word);

if ($special_word>is_special()) {


     $File = "words.txt"; 
     $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
     $Data = $word; 
     fwrite($Handle, $Data);
     fclose($Handle); 

} else {
    echo "Not special!!";
}

}

?>
```

Comment: I suggest opening the file before your `while` loop and closing it afterwards. That way, you don't have to keep opening and closing the file for each special word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $Handle = fopen($File, 'a');
```

instead of

```
 $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
```

Comment: or open the file before the while loop, and close it afterwards rather than open and close it again every iteration

Comment: @MarkBaker Yup, that'd be better.

Comment: I agree with Mark, it would save you a lot of processing to only open your file once, write all your data to it, then close it.

Comment: I would buffer the data and periodically flush it out instead of just waiting til the end to dump it, but this works. And yes, avoid unnecessary open/close cycles.

Comment: Nice you guys are great. Wait how do I make each one go on its own line?

Comment: To make each word go on its own line, you write a PHP_EOL of "\n" after each word